# How to post request for multiple strings in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, django-rest-viewsets

I am writing a viewsets that takes in an array of string values from the user and validates a table based on the post request.
I dont know how to take in an array in request.POST from the user and use the rest APIs in the Postman.
As for instance:

```
class newView(viewsets.ModelViewset):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication)
    serializer_class = NewSerializer

    def create(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        stringslist = ???
        # request.POST.????
        # Work with stringslist
```

Also, how to check this in Postman?

Answer (score 0):

```
class StringListField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.CharField()

class NewSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    string_list = StringListField()
```

Define String list field  and Add string list in your serializer

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        string_list = serializer.validated_data.get('string_list', [])
        # you can get string list here
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, 
        headers=headers)
```